# delphi webcam capture : why does it not work on laptop?

Tags: delphi

I have tried many webcam components for **delphi XE** (Tcamera, TJVAviCapture, sources codes I found...) Mostly of them work on my desktop computers, but does not work on my maptop (tested with 2 laptops).

[image]

They open this source video window, and then webcam panel.
Some of them work in DELPHI IDE but not in .exe generated by delphi !

Does someone know a reliable component (or a snippet) that simply display the webcam on any laptop or dektop without showing that video source window ?

Regards

Comment: Just a wild guess, do you have only one imaging input on those laptops ? Isn't that dialog being displayed to choose one of them, because the component found more than one ?

Comment: yes 1 ORIGINAL webcam only ! the combo box has 1 item inside !

Comment: Most probably reason is that the webcam is busy because you have some other software running that's using it?

Comment: I closed all possible softwares (including MSN and SKYPE) and webcam is not used by any software (light is off)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the Mitov Video Library for several years to do this sort of thing and am very happy with it. It's run my webcam application on many hundreds laptops and desktops all over the world without any problems.  Free for non-commercial use. Regularly updated. Good support. Source code available.

http://www.mitov.com/screenshots/videolab